# Wrong number or types of arguments in call to "PROCEDURE_1" when passing a Python list

Tags: python, sql, package, cx-oracle

I am trying to pass a Python list to an Oracle stored PL/SQL Procedure inside a Package. This procedure will then add the passed list as an argument to a table called TABLE_1.

```py
cur = conn.cursor()
MY_ARRAY = [1, 2, 3, 4]
cur.callproc('PROCEDURE_1', parameters=[MY_ARRAY])
```

The code above outputs the following error:

> PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PROCEDURE_1'

Below you can find how I have defined the Procedure_1 procedure as well as the list type:

```sql
create or replace PACKAGE procedure_1_pkg AS
   TYPE MY_ARRAY_TYPE IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY PLS_integer;
   PROCEDURE procedure_1(my_array MY_ARRAY_TYPE); 

END procedure_1_pkg;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY procedure_1_pkg AS
   PROCEDURE procedure_1(my_array MY_ARRAY_TYPE)
   IS
   BEGIN
    for i in my_array.first..my_array.last
      loop
        INSERT INTO TABLE_1(id) values(my_array(i));
    end loop;
   END procedure_1;
END procedure_1_pkg;
```

Help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Do you have a synonym? If not, you would need to do ``cursor.callproc("procedure_1_pkg.procedure_1")``!

Comment: Yes, I have a synonym defined. I forgot to mention it on the post.